# Xml Column Into Multiple Column With Separated Comma In Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using Sql Server 2012

I have table with single field within String containing xml format like below,

```
a
----
<data1>11</data1><data2>4</data2><data1>12</data1><data2>5</data2>
```

I want result table with containing separate comma for each column like this

```
data1|data2
-----------
11,12|4,5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your script. Your `a` column is not a valid XML type, so i need to append  as root element.

```
declare @strxml xml = concat('<t>', '<data1>11</data1><data2>4</data2><data1>12</data1><data2>5</data2>', '</t>')

SELECT
        STUFF((SELECT ',' + b.dat.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
               FROM   tmp.node.nodes('data1') b (dat)
               FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
              1, 1, '') AS a,

        STUFF((SELECT ',' + a.dat.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
               FROM   tmp.node.nodes('data2') a (dat)
               FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
              1, 1, '') AS b
FROM @strxml.nodes('/t') tmp(node);
```

applying your table. just replace `test3` and `yourcolumn`

```
SELECT
        STUFF((SELECT ',' + b.dat.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
               FROM   tmp.node.nodes('data1') b (dat)
               FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
              1, 1, '') AS a,

        STUFF((SELECT ',' + a.dat.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
               FROM   tmp.node.nodes('data2') a ( dat )
               FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
              1, 1, '') AS b
FROM test3 t
CROSS APPLY (select cast(concat('<t>', yourcolumn, '</t>') AS xml)) as t1(X)
CROSS APPLY t1.X.nodes('t') AS tmp(node)
```

Comment: can we not using declare xml variable,

Comment: i mean like from (SELECT ... ).nodes('/t') tmp(node);

Comment: try now. your column is not a valid xml type, so i need to append <t></t> as root element

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @XMLData XML 
SET @XMLData = '<a> 
                <data1>11</data1><data2>4</data2><data1>12</data1><data2>5</data2>
            </a>'

SELECT REPLACE
(
    @XMLData.query('data(a/data1)').value('.','varchar(100)')
    ,' ' -- replace the white spaces
    ,',' -- replace the white spaces with commas
) AS data1,

REPLACE
(
    @XMLData.query('data(a/data2)').value('.','varchar(100)')
    ,' '
    ,','
) AS data2
```

**OR**

> If you don't have any Root

```
DECLARE @XMLData XML 
SET @XMLData = ' 
                <data1>11</data1><data2>4</data2><data1>12</data1><data2>5</data2>
            '

SELECT REPLACE
(
    @XMLData.query('data(data1)').value('.','varchar(100)')
    ,' ' -- replace the white spaces
    ,',' -- replace the white spaces with commas
) AS data1,

REPLACE
(
    @XMLData.query('data(data2)').value('.','varchar(100)')
    ,' '
    ,','
) AS data2
```

**Note:-**

**1.** First we have space separated value...

**2.** To fulfill our objective we can use Replace function to replace the spaces with comma's.